# RETURN a value from other COLUMN based on the IF ELSE condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

[image: Dataout]How can I use function based on IF ELSE condition to use following result?

Condition are based on 'Priority' columns and return values from 'Check' column to new Column
Conditions: if Priority == CP 1 or CP 2:
return values from 'Check' to Column 'Final'
else:
return:
'No' to Column 'Final'
I tried and unable to return values from the column 'Check'

[image: Data Input]
[image: Expected data out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement if-else condition using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where)

```
import numpy as np

# check for conditions, Priority being CP1 or CP2
# when true return df['Check']
# else No
df['Final'] = np.where(df['Priority'].isin(['CP 1','CP 2']), df['Check'], 'No')
```

PS: if you post the data as a code or text, i would have been able to share the result